Can Harrison cohomology be written using Ext?
Just like Hochschild cohomology for associative algebras and Chevalley-Eilenberg cohomology for Lie algebras, it'll be nice (or disappointing?) if Harrison cohomology can be expressed in terms of Ext's. Is it possible?
I know that these cohomologies are uniformly dealt with by means of operad theory, and I'm curious how Koszul duality interacts with cohomology theories.
Thank you.

Ext for what kind of module category? Usual Hochschild cohomology $H^\bullet(A,M)$ is relative Ext but in the category of A-bimodules. Barr observed in the 1960s (see https://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/papers/cohnote.pdf ) that there is a commutative $k$-algebra A for which ${\rm Harr}^3(A,A^*)\neq 0$, and he infers from this that there is no way to express ${\rm Harr}^\bullet(A, \underline{\quad})$ as ${\rm Ext}_A^\bullet (X_A, \underline{\quad})$. On the other hand, for char(k)=0 Harrison cohomology is naturally isomorphic to Andre-Quillen cohomology which is a derived functor in some sense

In general, Barr's papers on Harrison (co)homology, and the Gerstenhaber-Schack paper on "Hodge decomposition" of Hochschild cohomology for commutative algebras, are a good window on Harrison cohomology, even if they might not be using a "modern" up-to-date POV (whatever that is). However I don't know if their perspective fits into what you are after.

Any module category is fine; I just wanted an interpretation from the derived perspective. Now that you've mentioned the isomorphism between Harrison cohomology and the André-Quillen one, I'm fairly contented. Thank you.
